# Windows batch file loop to check if files exist

Tags: batch-file

Sorry if this is been answered but I can only find parts and not sure how to put them together.

I have a list of files that will get populated over a varying period of time and I need some code that will loop through checking to see if each file in the list exists. Once all the files are there I want to send an email to a set list of 3 users then delete the files.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Examples of code you've tried or scenarios to process are always good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV3QgDq2TGw

Comment: Yeah I get that but I haven’t tried anything yet cause I haven’t found anything really that does what I want so I’m not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b in ("filename list.txt") do if not exist "%%b" goto :eof
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b in ("email list.txt") do ECHO start "email to %%b" "emailprogramnamepossiblywithpath" %%b
```

generic solution since you've provided no details about your proposed email generation procedure. The parameters that your email generator requires are unknown, but will obviously include the destination email address. The line is simply `echo`ed to show that the destination email address list is correctly processed. Remove the `echo` keyword to actually send the emails.

---

Edit in response to comment

From what I've read, outlook bloatware hasn't the capacity to do this, but don't quote me.

`mailsend` is a freeware product - Google is your friend.

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b in ("email list.txt") do ECHO start "email to %%b" mailsend -f phantom@yourcompany.com -smtp smtp.yourserver.whatever -t %%b -sub "all files present" -cs "us-ascii" -enc-type "7bit" -M "The required files are all present"
```

where `smtp.yourserver.whatever` is your outgoing SMTP server name should send an email from `-f` to `-t` with subject `-sub` and message `-M`. You'd need to read the documentation to determine other settings that may need to be supplied in your particular circumstances.

Sadly, an error report "It's not working" with no indication of what happened (error messages, didn't attempt to email when all files were present, attempted to email when not all files were present, attempted to email when no files were present, other undesired effects) leaves us guessing in crystal-ball land.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for not being clear. I've amended the code as suggested using proper file paths for the text files. changing the emailprograme string to the outlook path and removing the ECHO but it's not working. I'm not great with the batch language but in programming terms I want: IF (list of files) exists then send email. It just needs to be simple subject something like batch process complete. The email program is outlook. I'll keep trying and post a solution if I find one but thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Magoo., I work for a large financial organisation where everything is locked down so my options to install stuff are non existent and my ability to look at or play with settings is very limited. Not sure I could  use your solution, but it is a great idea non the less that I will take a note of if I am ever in a situation where I can and need to use it. For now I have just resorted to watching the folders over the 60-90 minutes it takes for everything to do what it needs to do. Thanks again everyone for your input.